# Here, I am plotting 1st two columns of the dataset. How can I put a bar legend with different colors for three column in that plot?

Tags: plotting, legending

Here, I have plotted the first two columns as a list plot. I want to put a bar legend with different colors for the third column. I want the points in the ListPlot to be colored.

[image]

Comment: Can you post your code as text rather than as a screenshot?  It will make it easier for people to edit it and show you what to do.

Comment: Hi @Michael Seifert. The code is attached here with.

datadd = {{250, 0.065, 12}, {149, 0.0909, 12.1}, {257, 0.0359, 
    11.9}, {124, 0.0501, 12.2}, {130, 0.0529, 11.7}, {291, 0.0229, 
    12.3}, {218., 0.0225, 11.9}, {294, 0.074, 12.5}, {253, 0.035, 
    12.8}, {259, 0.055, 12.7}, {270, 0.045, 12.6}, {265, 0.043, 
    13.1}, {262, 0.049, 13.2}, {205, 0.034, 13.5}};

u = {{#1, #2}} & @@@ datadd;
v = Transpose[u];

Answer (score 2):

After your clarifications [Sahabub Jahedi](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/76620/sahabub-jahedi) something like this (inspired by the link that I have provided above) should work:

```
ListPlot[Style[#[[{1, 2}]],Hue[(#[[3]] - Min[datadd[[All,3]]])/(Max[datadd[[All, 3]]] - Min[datadd[[All, 3]]])]] & /@ datadd, PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{Hue, MinMax[datadd[[All, 3]]]}]]
```

Notice that the legend is in accordance with the third column of your data set (i.e. datadd[[All,3]]).

Comment: Thank you so much, @demn. It's working.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear from your question if you want also the points in your ListPlot to be coloured. If this is the case then have a look [here][1]:

If not, maybe something like this

```
    GraphicsRow[{ListPlot[datadd[[All, {1, 2}]]],BarLegend[{Hue, MinMax[datadd[[All, 3]]]}]}]
```

Comment: Hi, @demm. You are absolutely right. I want the points in the ListPlot to be coloured. Thank you so much for providing the link.  Although, I didn't understand the link properly. I am trying to figure it out.